# Does Kiddush in shul require a minyan?

Tags: synagogue, minyan, kiddush

While I understand that Kiddush in shul Leil Shabbat and Yom Tov does not require a minyan halachically, I'm curious if based on the minhag that started this, does it assume that the recitation was needed only if a minyan was present and should it be dispensed if there is no minyan? Or should it be done, regardless?

Comment: What does minyan have to do with kiddush,it was instituted for the poor and destitute originally.

Comment: @sam it was instituted for the shul to do it for them. Random people don't say an extra Kiddush for them. Consider someone who comes late, do they have to make an extra Kiddush in shul on behalf of their non-minyan of one?